# Python: numpy.sum returns wrong ouput (numpy version 1.21.3)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Here I have a 1D array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328,
                  75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328,
                  75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328,
                  75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328,
                  75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328,
                  75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328,
                  75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328,
                  75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328])
```

And the sum of all elements in the array should be `75491328*8*8 = 4831444992`. However, when I use `np.sum`, I get a different output.

```
>>> np.sum(a)
536477696
```

That's what happens on my Jupyter Notebook using the latest version of Numpy. But when I use Jupyter Notebook of Coursera using old version 1.18.4 of Numpy, everything is fine.

How can I fix this bug? Is it a bug or is it because of me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by integer overflow, you should change the datatype of `np.array` to `int64`.

```
import numpy as np
np.array([Your values here], dtype=np.int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns same answer as you expect:

```
$ ./venv/bin/python --version
Python 3.9.7
```

requirements.txt

```
numpy==1.21.3
```

main.py

```
#!./venv/bin/python

import numpy as np
a = np.array([75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328,
                  75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328,
                  75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328,
                  75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328,
                  75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328,
                  75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328,
                  75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328,
                  75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328, 75491328])


print("output should be \n 4831444992")
print("calculated output \n",np.sum(a))
```

output

```
output should be 
 4831444992
calculated output 
 4831444992
```

**Any chance your actual code has different precision or an override for the datatypes ?**